# React Native Android: onKeyPress not working with numeric keyboards

Tags: android, react-native

I have an input component with `keyboardType="phone-pad"` and `onKeyPress`.

This is working on IOS but is not being called on Android for numeric keys (working for backspace though).

There is already a Github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19507

However, I didn't find a proper solution.

Note: I'm already using `onChangeText` but since the input has a `maxLength`, I need to do some logic even when the length is reached (in this case `onChangeText` is not called).

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution or workaround yet? I have the same issue and can't find a proper answer anywhere

Comment: Basically, I remember that a [PR fix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ee3e71f536127295ba4ea377e618499409a2e9ba) was merged lately but hasn't launched to production so I had to make a workaround that was specific to my scenario that doesn't depend on this feature. Consider checking the PR and creating a patch or overcoming the dependency on the event by using another like ``onChangeText``

Comment: @MajedBadawi now 2023, any solution for onKeyPress for physical keyboard? i still can't get it working